# Dask opportunistic caching in custom graphs

Tags: dask

I have a custom DAG such as:

```
dag = {'load': (load, 'myfile.txt'),
       'heavy_comp': (heavy_comp, 'load'),
       'simple_comp_1': (sc_1, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_2': (sc_2, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_3': (sc_3, 'heavy_comp')}
```

And I'm looking to compute the keys `simple_comp_1`, `simple_comp_2`, and `simple_comp_3`, which I perform as follows,

```
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster

task_1 = dask.get(dag, 'simple_comp_1')
task_2 = dask.get(dag, 'simple_comp_2')
task_3 = dask.get(dag, 'simple_comp_3')
tasks = [task_1, task_2, task_3]

cluster = YarnCluster()
cluster.scale(3)
client = Client(cluster)
dask.compute(tasks)
cluster.shutdown()
```

It seems, that without caching, the computation of these 3 keys will lead to the computation of `heavy_comp` also 3 times. And since this is a heavy computation, I tried to implement opportunistic caching from [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html) as follows:

```
from dask.cache import Cache
cache = Cache(2e9)
cache.register()
```

However, when I tried to print the results of what was being cached I got nothing:

```
>>> cache.cache.data
[]
>>> cache.cache.heap.heap
{}
>>> cache.cache.nbytes
{}
```

I even tried increasing the cache size to 6GB, however to no effect. Am I doing something wrong? How can I get Dask to cache the result of the key `heavy_comp`?

Comment: How do you evaluate your graph? In principle `heavy_comp` should only be computed once if you compute the keys using something like `dask.get(dag, [simple_comp1,simple_comp2,simple_comp3])`

Comment: @malbert, sorry I should've added details about how I was evaluating my graph, which I have now in my edit to the question above. Will the computation of both the keys `heavy_comp` and `load` only happen once the way I have shown above, or do the keys have to be formatted as a list as you have shown?

Comment: Without caching, every time you call `dask.get`, all necessary computations will be performed from scratch. Indeed caching should take care of storing the intermediate results such as `heavy_comp`. Unfortunately I don't have experience using the built-in caching. However your problem could be solved by calling `dask.get(dag, [simple_comp1,simple_comp2,simple_comp3])` (with the keywords given as a list as you say), as `heavy_comp` will then only be copmuted once. One more thing: In your example, you should only call `dask.get` instead of `get` and then `compute`

Comment: @malbert, so are you saying `dask.get(dag, simple_comp1,simple_comp2,simple_comp3])` will cache whereas doing `dask.get(dag, simple_compx)` 3 times will not? How sure are you sure about this? Do you have any references? 
Also, not sure what you mean by using `dask.get` instead `get` - isn't that I have shown above?

Comment: Regarding how sure, convince yourself: Consider this graph `import time; dag={'1':'heavy','2':'heavy','heavy':(time.sleep,1)}`. `[dask.get(dag,i) for i in ['1','2']]` takes two seconds, while `dask.get(dag,['1','2'])` takes only one second.

Comment: And I was saying that `dask.compute(tasks)` above doesn't compute anything, as the results were already returned by `dask.get`. `dask.compute` works on `dask.delayed` objects, while `dask.get` works on dask graphs

Comment: @malbert thanks! How about if I had a custom graph like this,

dag = {'load': (load, 'myfile.txt'),
       'heavy_comp': (heavy_comp, 'load'),
       'simple_comp_1': (sc_1, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_2': (sc_2, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_3': (sc_3, 'heavy_comp'),
       'merger_comp': (merge, 'sc_1', 'sc_2', 'sc_3')}
`

And I do `dask.get(dag, 'merger_comp')`, it seems to be computing (from the logs) "heavy_comp" each of the three times for "simple_comp_1", "simple_comp_2" and "simple_comp_3". Is there any way to format this for Dask to cache intermediate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on MRocklin's answer and to format code in the comments below the question.

Computing the entire graph at once works as you would expect it to. `heavy_comp` would only be executed once, which is what you want. Consider the following code you provided in the comments completed by empty function definitions:

```
def load(fn):
    print('load')
    return fn

def sc_1(i):
    print('sc_1')
    return i

def sc_2(i):
    print('sc_2')
    return i

def sc_3(i):
    print('sc_3')
    return i

def heavy_comp(i):
    print('heavy_comp')
    return i

def merge(*args):
    print('merge')
    return args

dag = {'load': (load, 'myfile.txt'), 'heavy_comp': (heavy_comp, 'load'), 'simple_comp_1': (sc_1, 'heavy_comp'), 'simple_comp_2': (sc_2, 'heavy_comp'), 'simple_comp_3': (sc_3, 'heavy_comp'), 'merger_comp': (merge, 'sc_1', 'sc_2', 'sc_3')}

import dask
result = dask.get(dag, 'merger_comp')
print('result:', result)
```

It outputs:

> ```
> load
> heavy_comp
> sc_1
> sc_2
> sc_3
> merge
> result: ('sc_1', 'sc_2', 'sc_3')
> ```

As you can see, "heavy_comp" is only printed once, showing that the function `heavy_comp` has only been executed once.

Comment: Thanks @malbert, that's verified!

Answer (score 0):

The opportunistic cache in the core Dask library only works for the single-machine scheduler, not the distributed scheduler.

However, if you just compute the entire graph at once Dask will hold onto intermediate values intelligently.  If there are values that you would like to hold onto regardless you might also look at the `persist` function.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `persist` just work for Numpy/Dask data structures such as arrays/dataframes?