# Dask opportunistic caching in custom graphs - part 2

Tags: dask

This is an extension of [Dask opportunistic caching in custom graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959647/dask-opportunistic-caching-in-custom-graphs). Suppose now, I have a custom graph like the following:

```
dag = {'load': (load, 'myfile.txt'),
       'heavy_comp': (heavy_comp, 'load'),
       'simple_comp_1': (sc_1, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_2': (sc_2, 'heavy_comp'),
       'simple_comp_3': (sc_3, 'heavy_comp'),
       'merger_comp': (merge, 'simple_comp_1', 'simple_comp_2', 'simple_comp_3')}
```

And I am performing Dask computation only for the last key:

```
import dask

dask.get(dag, 'merger_comp')
```

This seems to be calling the function `heavy_comp` each of the three times for `simple_comp_1`, `simple_comp_2` and `simple_comp_3`. Is there a way to get Dask to cache or store the results of `heavy_comp` so it is just called once?

Comment: Answered via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959647/dask-opportunistic-caching-in-custom-graphs

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to be calling the function heavy_comp each of the three times for simple_comp_1, simple_comp_2 and simple_comp_3. Is there a way to get Dask to cache or store the results of heavy_comp so it is just called once?

As mentioned in the comments.  Dask does not compute the function three times.  It computes it only once and shares the intermediate results.

(It's nice to provide answers rather than comments so that maintainers know they they don't have to track this question in the future)